# TypeError: router.back is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-testing-library

I'm testing the next.js back route navigation. But I'm getting this  error when running the test:

[image: error]

The back function:

```
     const router = useRouter();

     const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
         if (router) {
           router.back();
         }
       }, [router]);
```

Here's my test:

```
  it("should go back", async () => {

      const { baseElement } = render(<PageNotFound appTitle={"AppTitle"} />);
      expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();

      expect(screen.getByText("Back")).toBeTruthy();
      const backElement = screen.getByText("Back");

      fireEvent.click(backElement);
      expect(screen.findByText("All Systems Operational")).toBeTruthy();

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by mocking the back function on "next/router"

```
    jest.mock("next/router", () => ({
      useRouter() {
        return {
            route: "/status",
            pathname: "/status",
            query: "",
            asPath: "",
            back: ()=>{return "/status"}
        };
      },
     }));
```